# jade the "filename" option is required to use "extends" with "relative" paths

Tags: html, path, pug, relative-path, extends

I have following folder structure (simplified):

```
project
       - app.js
       - views
              - index.jade
              - layout.jade
       - public
...
```

I want to generate an index.html file from index.jade and use the following command in my Terminal (Mac OS X):

```
jade < index.jade > index.html
```

However I receive an error saying:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/runtime.js:231
  throw err;
        ^
Error: Jade:1

  > 1| extends ./layout

    2|

    3| block mainContent

    4|   center

the "filename" option is required to use "extends" with "relative" paths
    at Parser.resolvePath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:464:13)
    at Parser.parseExtends (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:483:21)
    at Parser.parseExpr (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:221:21)
    at Parser.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:122:25)
    at parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:102:21)
    at Object.exports.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:172:16)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js:144:21)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:943:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

I tried editing the line which causes the error in index.jade to:

```
extends layout
```

and

```
extends layout.jade
```

and

```
extends ./layout.jade
```

Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

if use "extend" or "include", the filename option must be used.

```
--filename "/absulute/path/to/your-file.jade"
```

Comment: There isn't `--filename` option (

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you are trying with

```
jade < index.jade > index.html
```

so jade have troubles finding the path (not sure why I think this is an issue) but if you try

```
jade < index.jade >
```

everything will be smooth.

or maybe try some automation with http://gulpjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `-p` option:

```
jade -p src/index.jade < src/index.jade > build/index.html
```

> Be careful! Jade drops last component of `-p` argument to concatenate with relative path.