# I cannot convert/compile .jade into .html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

Yesterday a friend noticed me about jade, easy way to do html templates and optimize html code so i decided to test it. I installed nodejs and npm but the error arrives when i want to export/compile from "archive".jade to "archive".html. The terminal doesn't work then.

PS: Look that the navigator text's syntax is correct but its not exactly what i want to do cuz i want to show (2 buttons, login and sign up) if session doesnt exists and ***"Hi 'username'"*** if exists

**command doesn't work 1: jade -p ./index-layout.jade -Po ./**

**command doesn't work 2: jade -p ./index-layout.jade -Po ./index.html**

**Template.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    //Foundation requeriments
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='../public/css/foundation.min.css')

    //Index/Home Page CSS
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='../public/css/home.css')

    //title
    title Inicio ~ LOL Ratings

    //body
    body
        header#header
            //nav height aprox 75px
            include ./navigator.jade
            h1#header-title LOL Ratings
            //Only the 'pro' or champion browser
            main.row
                section.column.large-8
                    h1#header-title LOL Ratings
                    p#slogan ¿Ya sabes que buscar?¡Encuéntralo!
                    form#searcher-wrapper.row
                        input.colums.large-10(type="text" placegolder="Busca tu 'PRO' o campeón por nombre" name="search")
                        button.colums.large-2(type="submit") GO
            section#analytics
                h1#analytics-title Predicción LCS
                //.align-center make be able center the columns (FOUNDATION FLEXBOX)

                //TODO ESTO SE TENDRIA QUE REPETIR CON UN FOREACH
                #analytics-wrapper.row.align-center
                    //logo team 1
                    figure.colums.large-2.team-logo#team1
                    //match information
                    .info
                        //align-justify makes the columns float left & right
                        .row.align-justify.team-names
                            //text-left-align makes the text align to the left way
                            .column.large-4.text-left-align
                                h3.blue-color Team 1
                            //text-right-align makes the text align to the right way
                            .column.large-4.text-right-align
                                h3.red-color Team 2
                        //Information and percentages
                        .row.align-justify.percentages
                            //text-left-align makes the text align to the left way
                            .column.large-6.text-left-align
                                h3 percentage1
                            //text-right-align makes the text align to the right way
                            .column.large-6.text-right-align
                                h3 percentage2
                        //color-percentage will be the "div" color, green or red depends the result
                        .progress#team2-color-percentage(role="progressbar" tabindex="0" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuetext="50 percent" aria-valuemax="100")
                            .progress-meter#team1-color-percentage(style="width: 50%")
                        //logo equipo 2
                        figure.colums.large-2.team-logo#team1
                //TODO ESTO SE TENDRIA QUE REPETIR CON UN FOREACH
```

**navigator.jade**

```
//top navigator
nav#navigator
    //navigator floating right:0, top:0
    ul
        li.nav.element
            a(href="pros.html") pros
        li.nav.element
            a(href="champions.html") champions
        li.nav.element
            a(href="teams.html") teams
        li.nav.element
            a(href="live-feed.html") live feed
    //VARIABLE
    //OPTION1: SESSION OFF ----> both buttons
    button#login.btn ¡Iniciar Sesión!
    button#signup.btn ¡Registrate!
    //OPTION2: SESSION ON ----> Hola 'username'
    p#loged-message Hola #[span#username.bold ]
    //VARIABLE
```

[image]

[image]

Any idea why i cannot do that? any idea? any suggest? thanks a lot.
I was reading and couldn't resolve it!

Comment: Is jade perhaps trying to get your input from stdin (the keyboard) instead of the file ? Try to give it ^D or ^Z and see what happens.

Comment: nothing so :( it just being close and its all what happens! (sorry for my english) @marged

Comment: try just `jade ./index-layout.jade -Po ./` (without the -p switch) I'm not exactly sure what the `-p` switch is for ([docs](http://jade-lang.com/command-line/) say: "filename used to resolve includes") but I believe includes are resolved automatically, but I don't use commandline much so I might be wrong. But this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248343/jade-the-filename-option-is-required-to-use-extends-with-relative-paths/33258346#33258346) says it "drops last component of -p argument" so that might be causing your issue.

Comment: done! thanks mate @laggingreflex